# Unable to import GDB folder in QGIS 3.8

Tags: qgis, file-geodatabase

I'm trying to import a GDB folder, downloaded from https://data.geo.admin.ch/ch.swisstopo.geologie-felsoberflaeche_hoehenmodell/ into QGIS 3.8 but I get an errormessage that data source is invalid. I have tested with QGIS on MacOS and also on OpenSuse. I have also tried to use ogr2ogr to get shape files. But also here I failed. Unfortunately, I cannot find out whether this file is corrupt or what are the problems to impede the working with these data.

Comment: Only ArcGIS tools can read FGDB rasters.

Comment: According to the [metadata](https://www.geocat.ch/geonetwork/srv/eng/md.viewer#/full_view/133b54a9-60d1-481c-85e8-e1a222d6ac3f/tab/complete), the dataset is a raster and as previously mentioned only ArcGIS can read GDB rasters.  The [product and ordering information](https://shop.swisstopo.admin.ch/de/products/geological_models/bedrock_elevation) states the data is also available in GeoTIFF, ESRI ASCII Grid and ASCII X, Y, Z formats, but I couldn't find download links for those formats.